# Linq Query filtering results

Tags: c#, linq, filter, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not super familiar with LINQ. Here's some code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                games = games.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }
```

Works as it should; however, what I'd like, rather than filtering results based on whatever text the user inputs, if the user inputs say "L" is there a way within the LINQ query to have it filter through the 1st letters of `x.Name` verses any `x.Name` that contains the letter.

I.E.  say I have...

```
League_of_Legends
LOTRO_
Dota_2
Call_of_Duty_4
Final_Fantasy_7
```

And the user inputs "L" rather than returning all but `Dota 2`, can it return only `League of Legends` and `LOTRO` as they are the only two who's names actually start with "L".

I'm assuming its something along the lines of... `games = games.Where(x => x.Name.Contains<***something***>(searchString));`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're looking for [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx). Note that this will work for any prefix, not just a single letter.

```
games = games.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(searchString));
```

If you want a case-insensitive search (e.g. where lowercase `l` matches `League_of_Legends` too), use:

```
games = games.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```